# what does it means $∥T(1_{[a,b]})∥$

Tags: functional-analysis

For each $f\in L_{2}(0,\infty)$, we set $Tf:(0,+∞)\to \mathbb{C}$ with $Tf(s)=\frac{1}{s}\int\limits_{(0,s)}f(t)dt$. For each $0<a<b$ i want to show that $∥T(1_{[a,b]})∥_{2}\geq\frac{b-a}{\sqrt b}$. But what does it means $\|T(1_{[a,b]})\|$ ? I can't understand this.

Comment: Please define the set $C$ and the meaning of the norm of $T(1_{[a,b]})$.

Comment: C are the complex numbers and norm is the $L_{2}$ norm

Answer (score 1):

$1_{[a,b]}$ is the $L_2$ function which is 1 between a and b and 0 otherwise. Presumably, your definition of T should have x in place of s on the right hand side. Applying T to $1_{[a,b]}$ will give a function f(x). This function will have an $L_2$ norm I guess (square f(x), integrate over x then take the square root).
I get $$T({{1}_{[a,b]}})(s)=\left\{ \begin{matrix}
   0\,\,\,if\,\,s<a  \\
   \frac{1}{s}(s-a)\,\,\,if\,\,\,a\le s<b  \\
   \frac{1}{s}(b-a)\,\,\,if\,\,\,s\ge b  \\
\end{matrix} \right.
$$
and then $${{\left\| T({{1}_{[a,b]}}) \right\|}^{2}}=\frac{({{b}^{2}}-{{a}^{2}})}{b}+2a\ln \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)+\frac{{{(b-a)}^{2}}}{b}\ge \frac{{{(b-a)}^{2}}}{b}$$
since b>a. The first 2 terms in the middle expression come from the integral of a positive function and so must be positive.

Comment: And must i compute the integral $\int\limits_{(o,s)}f(t)dt $ on $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: To find $T(1_{[a,b]})$ yes. The integral is easy enough, though you will get a piecewise defined function of s (think about the cases s<a, s between a and b and s greater than b).

Comment: ok it is easy to compute that. I found that $\|T(1_{[a,b]})\|_{2}^2=2alna-2alnb+2b-2a$ but i don't understand why the above inequality holds