# a) Compute $T(1_{[\alpha,\beta]})$ for all $0<\alpha <\beta<0$

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let H be a Hilbert space $H=L_2(0,\infty), dt) $ with $dt$ the Lebegues measure.

For each    $ f \epsilon \ H $, define the function $ Tf:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ by $(Tf) (s) = \frac{1}{s}\int_{(0,s)}f(t) dt  , s>0  $

a) Compute $T(1_{[\alpha,\beta]})$ for all $0<\alpha <\beta<0$

b) Show that 
$\|T(1_{[\alpha,\beta]}\|_2 \ge \frac{\beta-\alpha}{\sqrt\beta}$

My work:

a) We have to differ between three cases

**Case (i)** $s \in [\alpha, \beta]$

$T(1_{[\alpha,\beta]}) = \frac{s- \alpha}{s}  $

**Case (ii)** $s < \alpha$
$T(1_{[\alpha,\beta]}) = 0 $

**Case (iii)** $s > \beta$
$T(1_{[\alpha,\beta]}) = \frac{\beta- \alpha}{s} $

b) $\|T(1_{[\alpha,\beta]}\|_2 =(\int_{(0,\infty)}(\frac{1}{s}\int_{(0,s)}f(t) dt)^2 ds)^\frac{1}{2} $
And with this part I'm stuck.

For case ii) i have a contradiction. since I'm integrating over zero.
For case i) I have $ (\int_{(0,\infty}(\frac{s- \alpha}{s})^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ 
which has the value $\infty$
Similar for Case iii)
Where is my mistake?

I just also found here that someone has the same [Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/984234/what-does-it-means-%E2%88%A5t1-a-b%E2%88%A5). However I don't understand how they found their solution?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have a function $g = T(1_{[\alpha,\beta]})$ which is defined piecewise, you can use the piecewise definition to find $\int_0^{\infty} g^{2}$

Comment: @AlexZorn Oh, I totally forgot about it... 
Now everything makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to find the full $L^2$ norm here. Just note

$$\|T(1_{[\alpha,\beta]})\|_2 > \left (\int_b^\infty \left(\frac{\beta-\alpha}{s}\right)^2\, ds\right)^{1/2} =\frac{\beta-\alpha}{\sqrt \beta}.$$